# Degree of finite morphism between curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $f:X\to Y$ is a finite morphism of curves, we define the degree of $f$ to be the degree of the field extension $[K(X):K(Y)]$, and denote it $\deg f$.

One usually defines, for $f:X\to Y$ a finite morphism of nonsingular curves and $Q\in Y$ any point, a divisor \begin{equation}
 f^*Q=\sum_{f(P)=Q}e_P\cdot P
\end{equation} where $e_P$ is the ramification index. Then there is a theorem that says that for any such $f:X\to Y$ and $Q\in Y$ we have $\deg f=\deg f^*Q$.

My question is, if $X$ is a nonsingular curve and $Y$ is any curve, does it still hold that $\deg f=\deg f^*Q$ whenever $Y$ is non-singular at $Q$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.